# How to update yaml file using python?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I am newbie to python and YAML, I have an situation where I need to keep this file, appended with relevant data

```
__blocks: {}
        messages:
            CANMessages:
            -   CAN: !!python/unicode 'IuK-CAN'
                D0:
                - 13
                D1:
                - 0
                D2:
                - 0
                D3:
                - 0
                D4:
                - 0
                D5:
                - 0
                D6:
                - 240
                D7:
                - 0
                DL: 7
                Description: !!python/unicode 'clo'
                ID: 574
                Period: -1
                id: d3206970-20f2-11e6-bfd7-185e0fc5ec33
                timestamp: 1464013797.767
            -   CAN: !!python/unicode 'IuK-CAN'
                D0:
                - 13
                D1:
                - 0
                D2:
                - 0
                D3:
                - 0
                D4:
                - 0
                D5:
                - 0
                D6:
                - 240
                D7:
                - 0
                DL: 7
                Description: !!python/unicode 'cli'
                ID: 574
                Period: -1
                id: d37y069700f2-11e6-bfd7-185e0fc5ec33
                timestamp: 1487013797.767
            MOSTMessages: []
        pages: []
        settings: {}
```

Only content that needs to be appended here are the part from -CAN to timestamp

```
- CAN:                                        //1
 ..
 timestamp: xyznumbers
- CAN:                                        //2
 ..
 timestamp: xyznumbers
- CAN:                                        //n
 ..
 timestamp: xyznumbers
```

Each append here is an testing scenario for CAN.

Logic which I have written actually appends everything over and over again, I don't know how to just append required block.

```
data = {'__blocks': {}, 
                'messages': 
                    {'CANMessages': 
                     [
                      {'DL': 7, 
                       'Description': u'%s'%self.Description, 
                       'timestamp': current_milli_time, 
                       'D3': ['%s'%self.D3], 
                       'Period': self.Period, 
                       'ID': hex(self.ID), 
                       'CAN': u'%s'%self.CAN, 
                       'D6': ['%s'%self.D6], 
                       'D7': ['%s'%self.D7], 
                       'D4': ['%s'%self.D4], 
                       'D5': ['%s'%self.D5], 
                       'D2': ['%s'%self.D2], 
                       'id': 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', 
                       'D0': ['%s'%self.D0], 
                       'D1': ['%s'%self.D1]
                       }
                      ],
                       'MOSTMessages': []}, 
                       'pages': [], 
                       'settings': {}}            


        with open(fileMock, 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write( yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the output file for appending (`open(fileMock, 'a')`) and every time write the whole datastructure. You should probably not be using `a` at all on a YAML file, unless you want to have multiple documents in the file.

Append all the elements to the data structure `data` and then write it out once with:

```
    with open(fileMock, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write( yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
```

(note the `'w'` parameter to `open()`

Alternatively, you can read append, one item at a time, but then you have to read the YAML back into `data`, preferably with `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load()` to preserve your key order and layout, append the new data at the right place and then dump to the YAML file (again using `open(fileMock, 'w')` and not `open(fileMock, 'a')` )

Comment: Yes I agree on that and I accept this as genuine answer.